# Incorrect match for Rails route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `form_for` which generates me this html form:

```
<form id="new_programm" action="/programms" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
  .. some code etc.
</form>
```

So it is clear that this form is submitted via `post` and route it matches is

```
 POST  /programms(.:format)  programms#create
```

But when I submit the form it looks for `index` action. So it matches get request. I defined routes using `resources :programms`. How this could happen. Why my form matches different route?

My form_for:

```
<%= form_for po do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

Where po is a local variable passed when I render _form partial.
By the way, i render my form from in clients/show view. So my "po" varaible in created in clients#show method.

```
def show
  .. some code ..
  @po = Programm.new
end
```

in clients/show it is rendered using:

```
<%= render 'programms/form', po: @po %>
```

The most interesting thing is that if I inspect code in firebug it is clear that this form should be submitted via post. But it uses get.

Comment: where have you defined `po`?

Comment: `@po` in the view instead of just `po` ?

Comment: Try: 
`<%= form_for @po do |f| %>
<% end %>`

Comment: What happens once the `POST` to `create` action is successful?

Comment: @SonaliGupta, tried, the same issue.

Comment: @user3565829 try `<%= form_for(po, :method => :post) do |f| %> <% end %>`

Comment: @user3565829 post routes.rb

Comment: are you sure none of your js scripts are sending get request instead of post?

Comment: `<%= render partial: 'programms/form', locals: {po: @po} %>`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are passing `nil` object to `form_for` helper method, try this instead:

```
<%= render partial: 'programms/form', locals: {po: @po} %>
```

For debugging purpose, you can try this:

```
<%= form_for(programm.new) do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: No it still uses get request.

Comment: Add your full route file in your post, btw, I have updated my answer.

Comment: @SharvyAhmed as you can see, he is not following the usual RESTful conventions. So, `new` action will not help

Comment: @user3565829 post routes.rb

Comment: @Vineeth, he is using RESTful routes, since `resources :programms` will expose RESTful routes.

Comment: Yep. But if you can see, he is creating a new object in `show` action, which makes me cringe. IMHO, creation(not saving) of objects should be limited to the `new` action. @SharvyAhmed

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for helping. It was my BIG mistake. When I saw an error that my route does not match I thought that it doesn't match for my form, because I saw /programms url. 
  But actually I had already call my programm#create method and navigated to /programms url and after that my create method tried to redirect to some other url where it actually failed. And since I still saw the old url in browser I thought that it failed before calling programms#create.